# Is it possible to refer to "this" document in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, this

I'm using Mongoose in Node.js, and I am wondering if it is possible to refer to the currently selected document using "this" or a similar mechanism. Here is the use case I'm looking for :

Mongoose Schema :

```
const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    position: Number,
    date: Number,
    lastEventDate: Number
});
```

Let's say that, at some point in time, an event occurs.
For a document selected through its position, I want to update "lastEventDate" to the document's date.
Here is my dream code :

```
myModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {position: myPosition},
    {$set: {
        'lastEventDate': THISDOCUMENT.date
    }}
);
```

Note : I'm using $set here because the actual code updates subdocuments...

Is there a built-in "THISDOCUMENT" reference such as the one I'm dreaming of, to do it all in a single query ?
Or do I have to first query the value before updating the document (two queries).

Couldn't find anything on the web, and I'm quite the newbie when it comes to using "this".
Thanks for any kind of help !

[EDIT :] Precisions about the objective :

- I am in a situation where I only have the position "myPosition" to identify the correct document, and I want to set "lastEventDate" to the same value as "date" for that document.
- My question is about efficiency : is it possible to perform the update in a single upload query ? Or do I have to first download the "date" value before uploading it back to the "lastEventDate" key ?

Comment: Hey there, right now I am kind of busy with my own code! Nonetheless, I was playing around those days with the mongoose documentation. I am not sure if it helps, but some queries ‘this’ is the document, and others ‘this’ is the query, I remember reading. I can try to find it later, but if you want to gain time, please, see here, somehow, they talk about this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

Comment: maybe here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html I am not sure!

Comment: @JorgePires Thx for your time ! I just scanned both pages and digged a bit, but couldn't find anything helpful (taking into account my limited abilities...). It would make sense that "find"-oriented queries would refer the document as "this", and "update"-oriented queries would would refer the query as "this". Looking at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate, "this" should refer to the Query object. Yet, my question stands : is there a way to perform my update in a single query ? And finally : don't get distracted from your code ;-)

Comment: I like to help! futhermore, if I help you, I gain points, then I can ask other, it is a win-win game! Now my code works!

Comment: in two days if no one replies you, you can "pay" someone with your points, it is nice option for tough problems!

Comment: I think I know what you want and the this I have seen may solve the problem. Just let me know one think. Since you want "I want to update "lastEventDate" to the document's date." so, the document date is changing, right?

Comment: Maybe one solution is: you take back the document, make the modifications and save. Would that work?

Comment: @JorgePires : Thx again for your time ! I just edited the question to precise the objective. Yes, taking back the document does the job. But my question is about efficiency : can I avoid that "downloading" query ? The document "date" doesn't change (it's even an index), but I don't have local access to it unless I "download" it. Hence my question !

Comment: I am still not sure if I understood what you want. If I understood properly, you can use virtuals, or you can use something like `schema.methods.function`, this function has access to all the document properties, `this` will point to all the document properties. However, it is still confusing because since date does not change, what is the meaning of setting last `lastEventDate` to it. Why wouldn't your just set it when you create the document since nothing changes?

Comment: It's because my actual code is much more complicated ! I first create the document with its date, then execute a lot of lines to get values (such as the position of lastEvent, hence my question) I can finally update the document with. It results in more DB queries than needed overall, but I gain a much cleaner code with humanly conceivable encapsulation ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering all the information provided, I will venture on a possible answer!

You could try something like:

**Your schema JS file**

```
    const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        position: Number,
        date: Number,
        lastEventDate: Number
    });
    mySchema.methods.doYourThing(){
            this.lastEventDate=this.date; //it will set the lastEventDate
}

mongoose.model("myModel", MySchema, "mycollection")
```

Now, whenever you call `doYourThing()`, the action wanted will take place, you call it after you have a instance of the mode.

This is from my own code

```
const token = user.generateJwt(expirationDate); //send a token, it will be stored locally in the browser
```

it is inside a function that return an instance of `user`, and in the model `User` I have done a function called `generateJwt` like I have showed, and we have something like this:

```
return jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: this._id, //this is created automatically by Mongo
      email: this.email,
      name: this.name,
      exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000, 10), //Includes exp as UNIX time in seconds
      level: this.level,
      lastLogin: this.lastLogin,
      failedLogin: this.failedLogin
    },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET
  ); // DO NOT KEEP YOUR SECRET IN THE CODE!
```

It returns all the information of the user!

Please, do not hesitate to add comments and feebacks, I am not sure it is what you want, but that is why I have understood your request.

Anothe option is using Virtuals, they also have access to `this`.

Comment: Nice ! Didn't know about Schema instance methods and went to read https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods right away ! If I understand your thinking, is it possible to do something like this in my example : myModel.findOne({position: myPosition}).doYourThing().exec(); ? This would actually perform the update in a single "upload" query. If so, your answer is accepted ! In any case, thanks for your answer, it gives me ideas on how to improve my code in many cases ;-)

Comment: If I understood, well your problem, yes, you can use it! You could use something along de line `myModel.findOne({position: myPosition}).then((user)=>{user.doYourThing()})`. Anyone, you must always adapt since the problems is yours!

Comment: Ok ! I still don't know if it works the way I hope : perform the update directly in the DB without locally getting back the document. But at least it simplifies my code drastically. It's a win or a win+win. Answer accepted ! Thx again !

Comment: Moongoose works by instance, I have some images, see the book Getting MEAN with Mongo, Express, Angular, and Node. I have forgotten, you have to save: `myModel.findOne({position: myPosition}).then((user)=>{user.doYourThing(); user.save()})` . I have a series in mongoose, but it is in portuguese, I wanted to take advantage of the language I speak: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amymCoj5HxI&list=PLAqSYSz5TpHcltmZPga_648TxSwrgJ3ZV I believe I have used a  part of the abovementioned book.

Comment: When you have a instance of the model, you have a local copy of the doc, when you save, mongoose will save for you!

Comment: My suggestion, that is how I do, experiment in a simple problem, after that you implement in you complex problem!